# Is there any way to determine the best value of k in kmeans using CalinskiHarabasz?

Tags: matlab, k-means

I have a dataset that i want to cluster using k-means algorithm. However, i need to determine the best value of k that clusters the objects with similarity 0.2

I used this code

```
eva = evalclusters(num_data,'kmeans','CalinskiHarabasz','KList',[1:100])
```

but i doesn't find the clusters with 0.2 similarity

I'm using matlab 2015a. Any suggestion please

Comment: What do you mean *0.2 similarity*? Do you mean of each point within each cluster to each other point in that cluster? Or each point to it's cluster centre? Or each cluster centre to each other cluster centre? Are you sure k-means is the right algorithm for you then?

Comment: i mean the object within the same cluster are similar to each other with 0.2 similarity. I'm not sure with kmeans. Could you suggest other algorithm that may better

Comment: That's not what kmeans does - kmeans only lets you choose the number of clusters. You probably want hierarchical clustering. You should first figure out you algorithm before you ask questions on how to code it. You could start here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hierarchical-clustering.html